# Two different types of arrays of arrays

Tags: arrays, julia

I'm confused about the different types of arrays of arrays. Consider these two examples

```
a = Array{Float64}[]
push!(a,[1, 2])
push!(a,[3, 4])
push!(a,[1 2; 3 4])

b = Array[[1.0, 2.0], [3.0,4.0], [1.0 2.0; 3.0 4.0]]
```

I'm not sure how `a` and `b` differ. Suppose I intend to run a for loop over each of the elements in `a` or `b`, and multiple each element by 2. That is,

```
for i in 1:3 a[i] = a[i]*2 end

for i in 1:3 b[i] = b[i]*2 end
```

I time the run time of both lines respectively, but they are equally fast. Are `a` and `b` the same? If so, why does `a` even exist? It looks fairly complicated, because `typeof(a)` yields "Array{Array{Float64,N} where N,1}". What does `where` do here?

Comment: `b = Array[[1.0, 2.0], [3.0,4.0],...]` specifying `Array` here is something that you should do only if you need to overrule Julia's automatic type selection, in other words, don't do it unless you know what you're doing. Normally it's something you do when creating an empty array, since then Julia cannot infer the element type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both `a` and `b` are vectors but they allow different type of elements. You can check this by writing:

```
julia> typeof(a)
Array{Array{Float64,N} where N,1}

julia> typeof(b)
Array{Array,1}
```

Now `Array` isa [parametric type](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Parametric-Types) taking two parameters. The first parameter is type of elements that it allows. The second parameter is the dimension. You can see that in both cases the dimension is `1` which means both `a` and `b` are vectors. You can also check it using the `ndims` function:

```
julia> ndims(a)
1

julia> ndims(b)
1
```

The first parameter is allowed element type. In the case of `a` it is `Array{Float64,N} where N` while in the case of `b` just `Array` is printed. Before I explain how to read them note that the first parameter can be extracted using the `eltype` function:

```
julia> eltype(a)
Array{Float64,N} where N

julia> eltype(b)
Array
```

You can see that both `a` and `b` allow `Array` to be stored. First let me explain how to read `Array{Float64, N} where N`. It means that `a` allows storing of arrays of `Float64` of any dimension. Actually you could have written in a shorter way like this `Array{Float64}` as you can check that:

```
julia> (Array{Float64,N} where N) === Array{Float64}
true
```

The reason is that if you do not put a restriction on a tail parameter it can be dropped in syntax. The `where N` part is a restriction on the parameter. In this case there is no restriction on the second parameter.

Now we can turn to `b`. You see its `eltype` is just `Array`, so **both** parameters are dropped, thus there are no restrictions on them as explained above. So `Array` is the same as `Array{T, N} where {T,N}` as you can see here:

```
julia> (Array{T, N} where {T,N}) === Array
true
```

So the difference is that `a` can store arrays of any dimension but they must have `Float64` element type, while `b` can store arrays of any dimension and any element type. The distinction, in this case, has no performance impact as you have noted, but will have an impact on what can be stored in `a` and `b`. Here are some examples.

In this case they work the same, as you try to store an `Int` in them, but they allow only arrays:

```
julia> a[1] = 1
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type

julia> b[1] = 1
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type
```

but here they differ:

```
julia> a[1] = ["a"]
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type String to an object of type Float64

julia> b[1] = ["a"]
1-element Array{String,1}:
 "a"

julia> a
3-element Array{Array{Float64,N} where N,1}:
 [1.0, 2.0]
 [3.0, 4.0]
 [1.0 2.0; 3.0 4.0]

julia> b
3-element Array{Array,1}:
 ["a"]
 [3.0, 4.0]
 [1.0 2.0; 3.0 4.0]
```

As you can see you can store an array of `String` in `b`, but this is not allowed to be stored in `a`.

Two additional comments (both topics are a bit complex so I leave out the details, but just give you hints what is going on):

1. You are allowed not to specify element type of an array when defining it. In this case Julia will automatically pick its element type:

```
julia> [[1.0, 2.0], [3.0,4.0], [1.0 2.0; 3.0 4.0]]
3-element Array{Array{Float64,N} where N,1}:
 [1.0, 2.0]
 [3.0, 4.0]
 [1.0 2.0; 3.0 4.0]
```

2. The performance impact of the choice of element type of an array depends on the fact:

   1. if the type is abstract (that can be checked by `isabstracttype`; this impact type inference made by the compiler),
   2. if it is bits type (that can be checked by `isbitstype`; this impacts the storage layout),
   3. if the element type is `Union` (small unions can are handled more efficiently).

In your case both element types are abstract and non-bits so the performance will be the same.